# How to handle a sliding window of values over sequences that aren't multiples of the grouping size?

Tags: python, grouping, chunks

I have a list and I want to group my list into tuples of three elements using a sliding window approach.

Based on the parameters set in my loop, once `i` reaches the last two elements, the tuple of three becomes truncated because there are no more values at the end of the list.

What I need is it to use the beginning values, once it reaches that point. Please view the screenshot as it may better visualize my problem.

```
test = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]

for i in range(len(test)):
    print(test[i : i+3])
```

Output is:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
[(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
[(5, 6), (7, 8)]
[(7, 8)]
```

However, I need it to do:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
[(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
[(5, 6), (7, 8), (1, 2)]
[(7, 8), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

And then flattened for it to ultimately look like:

```
[((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
 ((3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8))
 ((5, 6), (7, 8), (1, 2))
 ((7, 8), (1, 2), (2, 3))]
```

[Screenshot of output for better clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gepMt.png)

What is one way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be ways to optimize the following, but one approach would be to use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and create the proper set of indices for it for each window subgroup.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint


test = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]

window_size = 3
length = len(test)
result = []
for i in range(len(test)):
    indices = (x%length for x in range(i, i+window_size))
    result.append(itemgetter(*indices)(test))

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)),
 ((3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)),
 ((5, 6), (7, 8), (1, 2)),
 ((7, 8), (1, 2), (3, 4))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is just fine, but I'll offer (what I take to be) a simpler approach:

```
test = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]

win_size = 3
groups = []

for i in range(len(test)):
        groups.append((test[i:] + test[:i])[:win_size])

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)],
 [(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)],
 [(5, 6), (7, 8), (1, 2)],
 [(7, 8), (1, 2), (3, 4)]]
```

Each time through the loop, we rearrange `test` so it is in the desired order, then create each group by slicing at the window size.

Although I think it's less readable, you could use a list comprehension as well:

```
groups = [(test[i:] + test[:i])[:win_size] for i in range(len(test))]
```

If the groups must be tuples instead of lists, either define `test` as a tuple initially or use `tuple(test[i:] + test[:i])` as appropriate.